# Triple Integral in mvc

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How i evaluate this $\iiint_{D}\sqrt{x^{2}+z^{2}}dxdydz$ where domain D is restricted by $y=x^{2}+z^{2}$ and plane $y=4$ ?

I've already known that $y=x^{2}+z^{2}$ is paraboloid and but i'm not sure about the domain. Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your domain is given by $\def\R{\mathbf R}$
$$ D = \{(x,y,z) \in \R^3: x^2 + z^2 \le y \le 4 \} $$
By this, we see, that we must have $x^2 + z^2 \le 4$, as otherwise, there is no $y$ fulfilling both inequalities, that is the point $(x,z) \in \R^2$ lies in a ball of radius $2$ around $0$. Parametrising, we can rewrite this as 
$$ -\sqrt{4 - x^2} \le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2} $$
for $x \in [-2,2]$ (otherwise $x^2 > 4$). Hence, the domain can be written as 
$$ D = \{(x,y,z) \in \R^3: x \in [-2,2], z \in [-\sqrt{4-x^2}, \sqrt{4- x^2}], y \in [x^2+z^2, 4] \}$$
giving 
$$ \int_D f(x,y,z) \,d(x,y,z) = \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,\int_{x^2+z^2}^4\, f(x,y,z)\, dy\,dz\, dx $$

Comment: because $y=x^{2}+z^{2}$, can i replace $f(x,y,z)$ with $\sqrt{y}$ for the integrand?

Comment: No, you do not have $y = x^2 + z^2$ all over $D$. You have $0 \le y \le x^2 + z^2$.

Comment: to integrate this is a bit hard, can we change integration from dxdydz to drd(theta)dz?